# jqgrid does not refresh the new value of the parameter in the URL

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a search function that passes the current value of an input text to filter the records in a jqGrid.
In the first keyup event, the parameter is passed correctly but in the second KeyUp event the console writes the URL with the parameter correctly but it is not updated in the servlet and only the first value appears.
How can I update the parameter with the current value of the input text?

My code

function searchOnkeyup(){

```
    var urlParam ='/servlet/myservlet?'+ $("#input").val()
    console.log(urlParam);

    $("#table").jqGrid({
            url: urlParam,
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [20, 40, 100000000],
            viewrecords: true,
            sortname: 'Search',
            sortorder: "ASC", 
            colNames:[
                'col1',
                'col2',
                'col3',
                'col4'
                ],
            colModel:[
                    {name:'col1',index:'COL1', width:65, align:"left",editable:false},
            {name:'col2',index:'COL2', width:60, align:"left",editable:false},
            {name:'col3',index:'COL3', width:130, align:"left",editable:false},
            {name:'col4',index:'COL4', width:75, align:"left",editable:false}
            ]
  });
$("#table").trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with the concept - the reason for this is that you every time call jqGrid creation when the user perform search.

This approach will not work since if the grid is already created it will noting do if you call it again in the same page.

To solve the problem you want it is needed first to create the grid instance and then create only function which will accept user input, change the grid parameter and do reload.

Here is a pseudo code

```
$("#table").jqGrid({
    url: init_url, // can be url, which does not return data
    datatype: "json"
    ...
});

function searchOnkeyup(){
    var urlParam ='/servlet/myservlet?'+ $("#input").val();
    $("#table").jqGrid('setGridParam', {url :urlParam});
    $("#table").trigger('reloadGrid');
}

var timer;
$("#input").on('keyup', function(e) {
    // do other things here
    if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        searchOnkeyup();
    },10);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have marked it as correct! but I was already aware of the concept that you mention of creating the grid for the first time, but it was a mistake of mine of automatic generation of Ids and I was not passing the correct Id of the grid.

The problem I have now is that if I press the key very quickly in the input text, the last key pressed does not load from the server because the grid has not finished loading the previous key, do you know if there is any property to control this behavior?

Comment: This is what I have missed in my post. In order to make this happen you will need to use setTimeout function. See my edited answer